How to copy files "drag and drop" to iOS Simulator?
I want to copy some files to my iOS Simulator, but i am getting this error:

Simulator device returned an error for the requested operation.


In the past I could easy drag and drop the needed files, but now I cannot, I tried to give full access to Xcode as well, but did not solve the issue, how can I solve the issue which I can be able drag and drop files to Simulator?


have you tried using Sharing from macOS into the simulator?

not working, is it working for you?

checking Xcode 15.4 -> iPadOS 17.5, sharing files doesn't appear to work, but using Safari to "AirDrop" to the simulator seems to behave aa expected.

@benc: but how I can put my files and folder inside safari for sharing it?

Not sure. I think I used to use several channels to put stuff into simulator, but its behavior is so varied, I thought it worth mentioning that the feature is somewhat-working.
